# Flutter DroupdownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4wvR.jpg)
In the above image of my DroupdownButtonFormField the width of the widgets is taking full of my screen. I want to customise it . Like left right distance and also the starting and ending portion and aprances details

Please help me.
Thanks in advance